# Image in UIButton is darker tharn original

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm trying to add a **UIButton** in a cell which already has a **UIImageView** in the background.

I put this code in `configureCell`

```
UIButton *mail = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 270, 40, 40)];
[mail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mail.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[mail addTarget:self action:@selector(sendMail) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:mail];
```

It works but the image in the **UIButton** is seems darker

[image: Original][image: Darker one]

I tried these but it didn't changed anything

```
mail.alpha = 1;
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:mail];
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this, and a solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem once and I solved it by setting the button's image for the UIControlStateHighlighted

```
[mail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Ok, I don't really understand why, but it works so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIButton *mail=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
mail.frame= CGRectMake(10, 270, 40, 40);
[mail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[mail addTarget:self action:@selector(sendMail) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:mail];
```